# How to enable side loading feature using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I want to enable side- loading feature for SharePoint online using power shell

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PnP using the `Set-PnPAppSideLoading`

All you need to do is connect to your site with PnP `Connect-PnPOnline`, then run `Set-PnPAppSideLoading -On`

Here's more info about PnP PowerShell: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: I run the script. Now how i check whether it is enabled or not

Comment: You can go to SharePoint central admin > sites > active sites, click on the site that you ran the script on, a pane will appear on the right side, click on the policies tab, under external sharing, click Edit. You will find the settings there.